# How to pipe the result of a grep search into a new vi file

Tags: grep, vi

I'm using `grep -e Peugeot -e PeuGeot carlist.txt` to search through carlist.txt and pull out some items and I presumed that `grep -e Peugeot -e PeuGeot carlist.txt | vi` would pipe it through for me but this is what I get:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

Comment: if you want to include it in a file, I'd first use vi on the file, and then :   `:read !grep -e Peugeot -e PeuGeot carlist.txt` . `:read !cmd...` will include the output of cmd... in the file (at the cursor's location)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "vi file". If you want the output to go into a file, use `grep ... > /tmp/foo`. You can add `&& vi /tmp/foo` on the end if you want to edit that file immediately.

Comment: In fact there's no such thing as a "vi file". `vi` operates on arbitrary text files; the files themselves are not directly associated with `vi`. (Or, as I just learned, `vi -` will cause `vi` to operate on the contents of `stdin`; `vim` does this, but not all versions of `vi` do.)

Comment: Related: [How to edit content from the standard input?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/737/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 129):

Running vi or vim with '-' as an argument makes it read the file to edit from standard input. Hence:

```
grep -e Peugeot -e PeuGeot carlist.txt | vi -
```

will do what you need.

Comment: For anyone seeing this, attention: it expects from `stdin`. In some cases you'll have to redirect from `stderr` to `stdin`, e.g: `valgrind my_file.out 2>&1 | vi -`

Comment: This removes search highlightings

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed, how do you expect to keep `grep`'s search coloring (composed of nonprintable characters) inside of Vim?  You can always just do a search *in* Vim.

Comment: I thought we can go with http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302 plugin within vim.

Comment: This answer is not quite accurate.  You are piping to vim here, not vi.  vi does not accept stdin.  You can confirm it is vim by opening your "vi" and then :version

Answer (score 17):

Apart of `vim -`, you can also use process substitution using the `<(command)` syntax, in example:

```
vim <(echo This is example.)
vim <(cat /etc/hosts)
```

See also:

- [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467) at Vi SE
- [Vim exec command in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517568/55075) at SO
- [Invoking vi through find | xargs breaks my terminal. Why?](https://superuser.com/q/336016/87805) at SU

Answer (score 12):

You should use [output redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
grep ... > newfile.txt && vi newfile.txt
```

Also, I think your `grep` can be improved:

```
grep 'Peu[gG]eot' carlist.txt > newfile.txt && vi newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Output redirection can also be used like this:

```
vi <(grep ...)
```

Even multiple command outputs can be redirected, as if they were saved in separate files:

```
vim -d <(ls) <(ls -a)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `~/bin/r`:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -eq 0 ] && set -- -;
exec vi -R "$@"
```

in `~/.vimrc`:

```
:  au StdinReadPost * set buftype=nofile
```

Then:

```
ls |r
grep -e Peugeot -e PeuGeot carlist.txt | r
```

and I've got

```
r- () { "$@" | r; }
```

in my `~/.bashrc,` so

```
r- ls -l
```

Comment: This requires explanation. What the hell is going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many effective ways to do what you want, either within vi(m) or outside vi(m).

Run your command, produce a (temporary) file, then edit the file ([see Joseph R.'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102090/52837))

```
grep -e"Peu[gG]eot" carlist.txt && vi /tmp/peugeot.txt
```

Run your command (in the background) to produce a temporary file, and edit the file, using ":e!" to refresh your file as it is produced (this is useful for logfiles, and other files being produced by another process, e.g. cron?),

```
grep -e "Peu[gG]eot" carlist.txt > /tmp/peugeot.txt &
vi /tmp/peugeot.txt
```

Run vi(m), and run a child process to create the temporary file, and then read it,

```
vi
:!grep -e "Peu[gG]eot" carlist.txt > /tmp/peugeot.txt
:r /tmp/peugeot.txt
```

Or, just switch to the file,

```
:e /tmp/peugeot.txt
```

Run vi(m), and use the double-bang "!!" to have vi run the child command, taking the results and inserting them into the current location (overwrites the current line, so make sure you have a blank line),

```
vi
i
here
empty
there
<esc>
kk
!!grep -e "Peu[gG]eot" carlist.txt
```

And now you can write the file (if you want to) to any filename,

```
:w /tmp/someotherfilename.txt
```

And [Petr Uzel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102097/52837) is also good,

```
grep -e "Peu[gG]eot" carlist.txt | vi -
```

Which reads from stdin